# Member 'string.Format(string, params object[])' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a page that displays a list of contracts. Each row contains an Amount, a Fee, and a Total that I'm calculating row that row.

I'm also trying to calculate a grand total, that sums up Total from the collection.

Here's what I have:

```
var contracts = _contractsRepository.Contracts.
    Select(c => new ContractViewModel
    {
        ContractId = c.ContractID,                                            
        Amount = c.Amount,
        Fee = c.Fee,
        Total = c.Sum(cc => cc.Amount) + c.Sum(cc => cc.AdminFee)
    });

// error here
ViewBag.GrandTotal = contracts.Sum(c => c.Total).ToString().Format("{0:c}");
```

I get a compilation error when I try to calculate the grand total that says:

> **Member 'string.Format(string, params object[])' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead**

Anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're misunderstanding strings.

`String.Format()` is a **static** method that takes a format string and a set of parameters.
You could call

```
String.Format("{0:c}", someDecimal);
```

However, if you only have a single value, you can call `ToString()` with a format parameter:

```
someDecimal.ToString("c")
```